# Sending http requests when the cookies are changing time to time

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I had some trouble sending http requests using python ,
because the cookies in http headers are changing automatically time to time .

How can i send http request without changing the cookie by checking at http request capture software ?

I normally send requests like this :

`import requests as req`
`url = "somesite.com"`
`headers = {"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"}`
`resp = req.get(url , headers=headers)`
`print(resp.text)`

Comment: Try to use `requests.Session`

Comment: @Tarique can you explain a bit more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you need `requests.Session` which automatically takes care of cookies.

here is a sample code to try:

```
from requests import Session

# create session object
session = Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'


# do requests now
url = "somesite.com"
resp = session.get(url)
```

Please do check out documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/